# The speed of light sets a lower limit to the rate at which a reference frame can pass through time. Is there anything that sets an upper limit?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light, time

Is there any "slowest" velocity that sets a cap on how *fast* a reference frame passes through time, or can you pass through time infinitely fast given a "slow" enough velocity?

Comment: Will whoever downvoted please explain why. Although this is a duplicate, it's not an obvious duplicate and it seems to me to be a reasonable question.

Comment: I didn't vote this down, but I can imagine why somebody might have. "Time" in physics is the quantity which a clock shows. It is NOT tied to a reference frame as many old style depictions of special relativity suggest, but it is tied to the clock, which may or may not be in a rest frame (hence things like the twin "paradox", where the clock is not tied to one rest frame but the analysis tries to pretend that it is). Time as depicted by a clock does NOT count some imaginary "planes of time", otherwise we would be back to a special frame of reference in which time moves "the slowest".